# want to add .html to certain urls (not all) using .htacess

Tags: .htaccess

I have some external sites pointing links (examples below) to my site that are not correct - they need to have .html added to the end. I have tried getting them changed on their side but cant - how can I do it so within .htacess I am manually adding the .html bit onto the urls I want to add it onto?

For example I have:

```
www.test.com/blue-boxes
```

and this needs to be `www.test.com/blue-boxes.html`

I am trying this:

```
RewriteRule ^(/blue-boxes)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

But its not working...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteRule ^blue-boxes/?$ /blue-boxes.html [L,R=301]
```

if the url is `www.test.com/blue-boxes` or `www.test.com/blue-boxes/` it will redirect to `www.test.com/blue-boxes.html`